# Selenium + Python: Cannot get href

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, href

I'm a newbie in auto testing and got a problem.

Cannot get href in debug mode, try to check it on google.com, my code:

```
browser.get("https://google.com/")

def beta_check_href(self):

    elem = self.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
    for el in elem:
        print elem.get_attribute("href")
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thx!

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace

```
for el in elem:
    print elem.get_attribute("href")
```

with

```
for el in elem:
    print el.get_attribute("href")
```

Note that `elem` is the *list* of WebElements while `el` is the *single WebElement* from `elem` list

Comment: Thx, got it! But still have this problem

Comment: Which one? Share exception log

Comment: I see no problems on the screenshot. Can you clarify what is your desired and current output?

Comment: Maybe I asked the wrong question. Where on screenshot you can see href links?

Comment: No problem any more! Thx a lot!